# The order of an Abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Here is the question: An Abel group $G$ is generated by $x$ and $y$, with $|x| = 16, |y| = 24,x^2 = y^3$.Then what is the order of G?

Comment: Lagrange's theorem is a pretty good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If you want to build the group homomorphism
$$\begin{aligned}\langle a|a^{16}=1\rangle\times \langle b|b^{24}=1\rangle&\to G\\
a&\mapsto x\\
b&\mapsto y
\end{aligned}$$
then what the kernel would be?